# What is the purpose of ordering by multiple columns?

Tags: c#, java, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am implementing an application in both C# and Java, and would like to have functionality similar to the ORDER BY function in SQL.  However, to do this I must understand the concept of ordering multiple columns.

I have tried writing simple SQL statements such as

`SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY Field1,Field2`.

On doing so, only `Field1` is ordered.  Is there actually any use at all for specifying multiple columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this: what if `Field1` row values are equal?

Basicaly, in your example, you firstly order by `Field1`, and if values are equal you sort by `Field2`

Example:

```
Field1 | Field2
A        4
B        1
A        3
```

`order by Field1, Field2`:

```
Field1 | Field2
A        3
A        4
B        1
```

Comment: I've actually read this online, however I'm not sure I understand 100%. Hence the question. Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: I've provided example in my answer

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it! :) Thanks for the great example. +1

Comment: Could you also explain what would happen if you order by 2 columns from different joined tables?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id ORDER BY t1.Field1, t2.Field2` will firstly order by `Field1` from `table1`, and then by `Field2` from `table2`. Do you need further explanations?

Answer (score 1):

> On doing so, only Field1 is ordered.

No. Second column is using for ordering when the first column values are equal.

Let's considering you create a table like this;

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    ([Field1] varchar(1), [Field2] int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl
    ([Field1], [Field2])
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 2),
    ('B', 1),
    ('B', 2),
    ('C', 4),
    ('C', 2),
    ('C', 1)
;
```

When you run this **[`query`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/724d4/1/0)**;

```
Select *
From tbl
Order by Field1
```

It gives you as a result

```
FIELD1  FIELD2
A   1
A   2
B   1
B   2
C   4
C   2
C   1
```

Which is normal because we order it only based on `Field1`. It didn't care anything about the other columns.

But when you run this **[`query`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/724d4/2/0)**;

```
Select *
From tbl
Order by Field1, Field2
```

This gives you as a result

```
FIELD1  FIELD2
A   1
A   2
B   1
B   2
C   1
C   2
C   4
```

Which is normal because we said to query; first, order the result based on `Field1` column values, if some `Field1` values are equal, order them based on `Field2` column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What would happen if you order by 2 columns from different joined tables?

Comment: @DotNET Think about like that; Just remove `order by` part from your query which using joined tables. After that, you can add `order by` part which tables' column do you want to sort in order of.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple rows with the same value for `Field1`, they will internally be ordered on `Field2`:

```
Field1 | Field2
-------+--------
 1     | 243
 2     | 23
 2     | 42
 2     | 278
 3     | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the table is "person", Field1 is "last_name" (family name) and Field2 is "first_name" (given name), then three people sharing the last name of "Smith" would then have the secondary sort of first name applied.

```
Smith Tim
Picard Bernard
Smith Alice
Smith Bob
```

becomes…

```
Picard Bernard
Smith Alice
Smith Bob
Smith Tim
```

As others said, successive sort fields come in to play when the prior sort field encounters duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify multiple columns in your ORDER clause, it orders by the first, then the second, then the third...etc. For example, if you order by Forename, Surname, the results will be ordered first by Forename, i.e. all the A's first, then by Surname, so each of the A's will be ordered by their surname, so if you had two Albert's in you data, appearing in your unsorted table in the order of Albert Einstein and Albert Davies, they would appear in the list by order of their surname, i.e.

```
Forename   |   Surname
Albert     |   Davies
Albert     |   Einstein
Arthur     |   Dent
```

If you just order on forename you'll get the following (providing of course that Einstein appears above Davies in your unsorted table):

```
Forename   |   Surname
Albert     |   Einstein
Albert     |   Davies
Arthur     |   Dent
```